# Check if multiple folders exist?

Tags: javascript, gulp, fs

I use fs.stat to check if a folder exists:

```
fs.stat('path-to-my-folder', function(err, stat) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('does not exist');
    }
    else{
        console.log('does exist');
    }
});
```

Is there a way to check the existence of multiple paths using only one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the File System API doesn't have a function to check if multiple folders exists. You just have to call the `fs.stat()` function multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

`fs` doesn't have anything that does it out of the box, but you can create a function to do it.

```
function checkIfAllExist (paths) {
  return Promise.all(
    paths.map(function (path) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
          err && reject(path) || resolve()
        });
      });
    }))
  );
};
```

You would use this like this:

```
checkIfAllExist([path1, path2, path3])
  .then(() => console.log('all exist'))
  .catch((path) => console.log(path + ' does not exist')
```

You could tweak it to fail at different points and whatnot, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Shorter and maybe cleaner: `paths.map(path => new Promise(...))`

Comment: Are you implying just using ES6 format? I normally do, but I kept it in the same format as the original question. It's a lot cleaner looking in ES6 format.

Comment: Yes. BTW `function (err, stat) => {` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Just didn't convert it quite right. =p